# How to print multiple elements in a page individually using css?

Tags: html, css, printing

My page structure is like

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="/" onClick="window.print();">Print One</a> // I want this to print "My Content 1"
    <a name="one" id="one">One</a>
    <div class="one">My Content 1</div>

    <a name="two" id="two">Two</a>
    <a href="/" onClick="window.print();">Print Two</a> // I want this to print "My Content 2"
    <div class="two">My Content 2</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I want to implement two different print buttons to print the specified element at a time. I'm familiar with CSS approach of printing and blocking the anti-print elements like sidebar, footer. For some reason, I don't want to use jquery though a lightweight js can be used.

Comment: If you would like to use a light weight JS library alternative to jQuery you could use [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com). It has similar syntax to jQuery so you might feel right at home. The source and documentation are on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto)

Comment: @hradac I think using libraries for this purpose would be overkill. If there isn't any solution with css, I've a last option to change the whole page structure.

Comment: The entire library is about 7.5k minified and gzipped. That is smaller than most of the CSS I work with, and you mentioned 'a lightweight js can be used', but it's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create two style templates, one that hides all but content 1, and other that hides all but content 2.  Set both style blocks with ids (ex. `id="printOne"`), `media="print"` and with attribute `disabled` (or `disabled="disabled"` in XHTML)

when you click the print link you can set `disabled = false` on the appropriate style template to enable it for printing.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XgGLH/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style id="printOne" type="text/css" media="print" disabled>
        a, .two {display:none;}
        .one {display:block;}
    </style>
    <style id="printTwo" type="text/css" media="print" disabled>
        a, .one {display:none;}
        .two {display:block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return printContent('printOne');">Print One</a> <!--I want this to print "My Content 1"-->
    <a name="one" id="one">One</a>
    <div class="one">My Content 1</div>

    <a name="two" id="two">Two</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return printContent('printTwo');">Print Two</a> <!--I want this to print "My Content 2"-->
    <div class="two">My Content 2</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printContent(pid) {
            document.getElementById('printOne').disabled = !(pid === 'printOne');
            document.getElementById('printTwo').disabled = !(pid === 'printTwo');
            window.print();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for both, the solution and reference to jsfiddle.